# What is the name of the event that reversed the effects of Thanos' Snap?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

What do you call it when everyone

> reappeared after Smart Hulk performed the second Snap in *Avengers: Endgame*.

I remember is was called something like "*Bliss*". This event was seen in action in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*.

Comment: When you say “something like Bliss”, some people (in the real world, not the movies) might have referred to it as the Rapture, referencing the [apocalyptic belief held by some Christians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapture). Some other people then went with “Snapture”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called 'The Blip.' In *Far From Home*:

> **Aunt May:** Uh, yeah. Yes, it is. That’s a new beard.
>
> **Happy Hogan:** It’s my Blip beard, because I grew it in the blip. Blip beard.
>
> **Aunt May:** I see.

Comment: This is the term the question is asking about, but the quote actually suggests the Blip is period between the snap and the return, or the whole episode in a broader sense. Pretty hard to grow a beard in the three seconds of Banner's snap.

Comment: @Nolimon A pedantic person would state that if he grew it in the period between Thanos' and Smart Hulk's Snaps and hadn't shaved it until that conversation he did also grow it in those "3 seconds". But I wouldn't state that, not at all.

Answer (score 10):

This is made pretty clear in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, the event when people came back from Smart Hulk's snap was called **The Blip**.

> **Betty Brant:** Historic. Over five years ago, half of all life in the universe, including our own Midtown High was wiped from existence. But then eight months ago, a band of brave heroes brought us back. They called it the Blip. Those of us who blipped away came back the same age. But our classmates that didn't blip grew five years older.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home*</sub>

And it's not even just the high school kids that call it The Blip as Aunt May does when she's giving her talk for her charity.

> **Aunt May:** When I first blipped back to my apartment, the family living there was very confused. The wife thought that I was a mistress. The Grandma thought that I was a ghost. It was, it was really a mess. Thank you all for coming out to support those who we’re misplaced by the Blip, and, of course, thank you Spider-Man!
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home*</sub>

Just to be as complete as possible, whilst it's never referred to by name in universe it is alluded to being called The Snap - the event when those people vanished.Various heroes say "why Thanos snapped his fingers" and words to that effect.

Kevin Feige, President of Marvel Studios, has previously commented on this difference in an interview with Fandango.

> **Fandango: For so long, fans referred to what happened with Thanos as “The Snap,” but now in this film we are introduced to “The Blip.” Where did the Blip come from? Did the naming of it come fast for you?**
>
> **Kevin Feige:** It came pretty fast. We always referred to it as the Blip, and then the public started referring to it as the Snap. We think it's funny when high school kids just call this horrific, universe-changing event the Blip. We've narrowed it down to, the Snap is when everybody disappeared at the end of *Infinity War*. The Blip is when everybody returned at the end of *Endgame*… and that is how we have narrowed in on the definitions.
>
> <sub>[Fandango, MARVEL'S KEVIN FEIGE ON THE MCU MULTIVERSE, 'FAR FROM HOME' POST-CREDITS SCENES AND THE FUTURE OF SPIDER-MAN](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/marvels-kevin-feige-on-the-mcu-multiverse-far-from-home-post-credits-scenes-and-the-future-of-spider-man-753812)</sub>